# Receiving scapy packets python

Tags: python, scapy

I'm building a packet and sending it with scapy from a server program.

How can I receive this packet with my client program so I can modify it.
I need all packet fields not just data.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try collecting it with Wireshark. You can use Wireshark to inspect all layers of OSI model.

Answer (score 0):

you could use tshark and pyshark wrapper to do it with python - 
`pip install pyshark` and if you are in linux: `apt-get/yum install tshark`
 to implement the capture you should create file to capture at, for example `/tmp/packetCapture.cap` ( you might need to create file manualy if you don't run it with root)
then in script you'll just have to run the liveCapture function to catch what you need.
all and all, it should look like this:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import pyshark

    # Open saved trace file 
    cap = pyshark.FileCapture('/tmp/mycapture.cap')
    # Sniff from interface
    capture = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface='eth0')
    capture.sniff(timeout=10)
```

hope this helps.